# RSS feed displays, but does not validate because of a 404 error

Tags: rss

I have created an RSS and Atom feed [as specified here](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/rss-and-atom-feeds). You can view my example feeds: [RSS](https://beta.nathansnelgrove.com/feed.rss) or [Atom](https://beta.nathansnelgrove.com/feed.atom).

The files are both called feed.`feedtype`.twig, as specified. I am running Craft CMS 4.

As you can see from visiting both links, the feeds load in your browser, but the console says there is a 404 error. Consequently, the feeds do not validate.

It is worth mentioning I have set up caching as per [this article](https://nystudio107.com/blog/static-caching-with-craft-cms). I don't know why that should affect anything, but I do know I don't have this problem locally with DDEV.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: it turns out I had an nginx error on my server. It allowed the feed to be viewed, but not fetched remotely. My apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had an nginx error on my server. It allowed the feed to be viewed, but not fetched remotely. My apologies!

In brief: I had the following lines setup in my `nginx.conf` file:

```bash
# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
           access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}
```

All I had to do was remove RSS and Atom from that list.

```bash
# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
           access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}
```

Everything loads now, thankfully.

Comment: Feel free to mark your own answer as "The Answer", its allowed and encouraged to help others find solved / unsolved questions. Cheers!

Comment: I can accept it as the answer in 3 hours — thanks!